# Sum columns based on condition on another columns

Tags: python, for-loop, pyspark

I have a dataframe as follows and if ts1_diff,ts2_diff,ts3_diff is >= 0 then only sum corresponding ts1 to ts3 columns.So for id=1,ts3_diff>=0 so the value for SUM = 5, for id = 2,all ts1_diff,ts2_diff,ts3_diff is >=0 so we sum(ts1,ts2,ts3)= 10, I am expecting the Column 'SUM'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMmcL.png)

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.